# Determine growth in value in a specific time range

Tags: mysql, sql, analytics, mysql-5.7, trend

Given the following data set example, how should I structure my `SQL` query in order to determine if the `value` has grown over time (given a time range in the query) for a specific `UserId` by returning either a positive/negative growth percentage result or a `true`/`false` result

| UserId | timestamp | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1617711825 | 350 |
| 1 | 1617711829 | 400 |
| 1 | 1617711830 | 450 |
| 5 | 1617711831 | 560 |

Given the above example, we can observe that the `value` for `UserId=1` has grown by a certain percentage.

The expected result would be:

| UserId | growthPercentage | hasValueIncreased |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 50% | 1 |

Comment: Edit your question and show the results you want.

Comment: @GordonLinoff ok

Comment: Which version of MYSQL are you using?

Comment: @KaziMohammadAliNur MySQL 5.7

Comment: Do you just want to compare last value and first value for a userid in a time period?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the first and last values and then do whatever calculation you like.  One method is:

```
select userId, value_first, value_last,
       (value_first < value_last) as is_growing,
       100 * ((value_last / value_first) - 1) as increase_percentage
from (select t.*,
             first_value(value) over (partition by userId order by timestamp) as value_first,
             first_value(value) over (partition by userId order by timestamp desc) as value_last
      from t
     ) t
group by userId, value_first, value_last;
```

Comment: Thank you, can I filter by a time range?

Comment: @YairNevet . . . Yes.  The filter would go in the subquery.

Comment: Can I determine if the value increases serially during a specific time-series/range? That is, day after day.

Comment: @YairNevet . . . That is different from the question you have asked here.  I would suggest asking a *new* question.  Be clear on the sample data, desired results, and explanation.

Comment: got you, I'll create one

Comment: new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66969628/determine-serially-growth-in-value-during-a-specific-time-range

Answer (score 0):

Schema and insert statements:

```
 create table mytable(UserId int,timestamps timestamp,value int);

 insert into mytable values(1,  FROM_UNIXTIME(1617711825),  350);
 insert into mytable values(1,  FROM_UNIXTIME(1617711829),  400);
 insert into mytable values(1,  FROM_UNIXTIME(1617711830),  450);
 insert into mytable values(5,  FROM_UNIXTIME(1617711831),  560);
```

Query:

```
 select usermin.userid, 100*(usermax.value-usermin.value)/usermin.value as growthPercentage,
 (case when usermax.value>usermin.value then 1 else 0 end)hasValueIncreased
 
 from
 (SELECT USERID, VALUE  FROM mytable where userid=1
 order by timestamps 
 limit 1) usermin
 inner join
 (SELECT USERID, VALUE  FROM mytable where userid=1
 order by timestamps desc
 limit 1) usermax
 on usermin.userid=usermax.userid
```

Output:
|userid | growthPercentage | hasValueIncreased
|-----: | ---------------: | ----------------:
|     1 |          28.5714 |                 1

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=b13a03662529a86665dd215ffd933b1c)*