# Determine persistent growth in value during a specific time range

Tags: mysql, sql, analytics, mysql-5.7, trend

Given the following data set example, how should I structure my `SQL` query to determine if the `value` has **gradually** grown day-by-day given a time range in the query for a specific `user_id` by returning a `true`/`false` result

| user_id | date | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4/1/2021 12:00 | 350 |
| 1 | 4/2/2021 12:00 | 400 |
| 1 | 4/3/2021 12:00 | 450 |
| 5 | 4/4/2021 12:00 | 560 |
| 5 | 4/5/2021 12:00 | 566 |
| 5 | 4/6/2021 12:00 | 483 |
| 5 | 4/7/2021 12:00 | 570 |

Given the above example, we can observe that the `value` for `user_id=1` has gradually grown day after day while the `value` for `user_id=5` has grown for 2 consecutive days, but bounced down on the third day.

Therefore, the expected result-set for `user_id=1` and `user_id=5` would be:

| user_id | value_is_increasing |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | true |

The expected result-set for `user_id=5` would be:

| user_id | value_is_increasing |
| --- | --- |
| 5 | false |

**Declaration Update:** I would like to determine if the value has constantly grown within a specific time range in a day-by-day manner (consecutive). Moreover, individual value points should be considered noisy (they bounce up and down even though they trend upward or downward over time) and affect the result.

Comment: This sort of thing is surprisingly difficult to specify correctly. Can you [edit] your question to be more specific about your criteria for serial growth? Do you want to compare yesterday's average value with today's? Are your individual `value` points noisy: do they bounce up and down even though they trend upward or downward over time?

Comment: @O.Jones I added a declaration update per your request

Comment: By what percentage has it (serially) grown?

Comment: @Strawberry any positive percentage

Comment: ??? So what's 'serial' about it?

Comment: @Strawberry by serial I mean constantly

Comment: So you simply mean that the numbers are increasing

Comment: @Strawberry correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use aggregation:

```
SELECT user_id, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(value ORDER BY date) = GROUP_CONCAT(value ORDER BY value) value_is_increasing
FROM tablename
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 
   AND COUNT(*) = COUNT(DISTINCT value)
```

The condition `COUNT(*) > 1` will return only users that have more than 1 values in the table.
The condition `COUNT(*) = COUNT(DISTINCT value)` will return only users that have only distinct values in the table.
`GROUP_CONCAT(value ORDER BY date)` will return values order by `date` and
 `GROUP_CONCAT(value ORDER BY value)` will return values order by `value`.
If the results of the 2 `GROUP_CONCAT()` are the same this means that `value`s are monotonically increasing.

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=36d94c6f11887ffae9990e037698fabe).

Comment: With a growing amount of data, the following expression would be scalable and performant over time: `GROUP_CONCAT(value ORDER BY date) = GROUP_CONCAT(value ORDER BY value) value_is_increasing` ?